# На сайте появляется инородная реклама

Tags: vkontakte-api, реклама

На странице [сайта](http://m-camper.ru/discussion.php) иногда появляется инородный блок с рекламой.

[image: img]
Причем в коде этого блока подключаются скрипт `autocontext2.js`, ссылки на `autocontext.begun.ru`.

Он вставляется прямо во внутрь виджета ВК. Как можно заблокировать доступ к сайту этому `autocontext.begun.ru`? в исходном коде сайта никаких скриптов инородных нет, только виджет ВК подключается и всё

Comment: Раз на сайте всё "чисто", то ищите у себя проблемы. У моего друга происходила подмена скрипта яндекс.метрики.

Comment: Вы можете скрыть этот блок - посмотрите, что у него в потрохах (id, классы etc) и пропишите в CSS display:none.

Comment: @klopp это не решение проблемы, плохо такое советовать. Вконтакте не встраивает рекламу в виджеты.

Comment: >Вконтакте не встраивает рекламу в виджеты

Я погуглил - много где сообщается, что Бегун начал с ними сотрудничать. Самому проверить негде, но начал бы с анализа того, что на самом деле приходит с VK.Widgets.Comments, по картинке уж очень похоже на бегуновский контекст.

Comment: @klopp посмотрим, что ответит агент поддержки ВК по этому вопросу. Что-то уж не верится в это. В скрипте VK быстрый поиск ничего не дал.

Comment: Ы... http://begun.ru/advertiser/services/social.php

>Затем Ваши объявления транслируются в социальной сети «ВКонтакте» и в **ее приложениях**.

Comment: хм, кстати, эта реклама появляется пока что только у одного человека, т.е. вполне вероятно, что как раз такая вот реклама от ВК?

Comment: хм, да, это точно ВК делает, т.к. id дива на сайте ads_div, и такое же название у блоков рекламных ВК на их сайте слева. Спасибо всем...